# Does the result of SELECT MAX([ColumnName]) have a column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does the result of SELECT MAX([ColumnName]) have a column name? I know the result is a view of only one record and I'd thought this view has the original column name as the result column name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not but you can give it one

```
SELECT MAX([ColumnName]) AS MaxName
```

If you think about it you will see why your assumption is wrong. What if the code was like this:

```
SELECT MAX([ColumnName]), MIN([ColumnName])
```

Which of the two will take the name of the column?

Comment: I was going to make a post about the problem with MIN/MAX, but of course, SQL is poor enough to let you have two columns with the same name (even though it shouldn't)

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that. How absurd. Well then again it would be useless to assume the name of the column because it would be the same as having no column name (i.e. you cannot distinguish by name).

Answer (score 1):

By default no, there is no particular column name. If you specify an alias it will have.

```
SELECT MAX([ColumnName]) as [max_value_column_name]
```